# How to bring Xamrin MAC app to foreground programmatically?

Tags: macos, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin-studio, xamarin.mac

How to bring Xamarin MAC app to foreground programmatically, by clicking on the local notification? How can I achieve it? I have written below code for the local notification. On clicking on that local notification I want to foreground my app.

```
NSUserNotificationCenter center = NSUserNotificationCenter.DefaultUserNotificationCenter;

    NSUserNotification notification = new NSUserNotification();
    notification.Title = title;
    notification.Subtitle = content;
    notification.InformativeText = "TEST";
    notification.SoundName = NSUserNotification.NSUserNotificationDefaultSoundName;
    notification.DeliveryDate = NSDate.FromTimeIntervalSinceNow(1);  

    center.ScheduleNotification(notification);

    center.DidDeliverNotification += (s, e) =>
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Notification Delivered");              
    };

    center.DidActivateNotification += (s, e) =>
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Notification Touched");                
    };
```

Thank you in advance,
Vivek

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `NSWorkspace.SharedWorkspace.LaunchApp` to "launch" your app, it does not matter if the app is already running or not, and you can use `NSWorkspaceLaunchOptions.HideOthers` to bring forward just the last active window of that app.

```
center.DidActivateNotification += (s, e) =>
{
    Console.WriteLine("Notification Touched");
    NSWorkspace.SharedWorkspace.LaunchApp(NSBundle.MainBundle.BundleIdentifier, NSWorkspaceLaunchOptions.HideOthers, new NSAppleEventDescriptor(), IntPtr.Zero);
};
```

Comment: Thank you so much. It worked for me.

After applying your solution, I noticed that
(1) When the app is already opened and not having focus and I clicked on the received notification, then app got the focus and came front to the screen - that's great.
(2) When the app is minimized and I clicked on the received notification, it launched the app from the background but the app has't had the focus on it. So is there any way to get focus on the app after launching it from the background ?